# Change app name in django, now user can't see app in the admin backend?

Tags: django

I'm using the Coltrane Blog.
I changed

Class Meta:
        app_label = 'Blog'

Now Entries in under Blog instead of Coltrane. Great this is what I
want.

However now I have created a user with privileges to add, edit and
delete entries for Coltrane app. I assigned the privileges under Users
in the admin backend.

Now when my user signs in he can't see the Blog? If I take away
app_label then the user sees the blog as Coltrane. If I assign
Superuser status to a user they can see the app.

Is it not possible to changes an app_label and still have a user see
the app?

Answer (score 1):

If the user is just a staff user, and not a superuser, you need to make sure the user has privileges for that model.

I would try going to that user's record and looking at their list of privileges. You may need to add privileges specific to the newly named app.

Comment: I've given privileges to the coltrane app. but it seems because i've changed the app name they don't see the app anymore. even giving all the privileges that user still can not see the app if i change the name.

Comment: is right, your users will need the default `Blog.(...)` permissions.

Comment: I have added the permissions. They are listed as coltrane permissions.